# Random selection in percentage

Tags: random, percentages

I have $3$ lists of things. I want to choose things randomly from this lists.

But have percentage limitation on the lists.
Like I can select only $60$% things from $1$st list, $30$% from $2$nd list & $10$% from $3$rd list.

I want to achieve this by a mathematical formula which can provide me a random selection for this lists in the provided percentages.

So lets say I am going to select $100$ things from this lists randomly. Then I must choose $60$ things from $1$st list, $30$ from $2$nd & $10$ from $3$rd list.

But the selection of the list must be random. I can not go straight away to select $60$ things from $1$st list then $30$ from $2$nd & so on.

As I am not that good in maths, can anyone please help me out so solve this problem.

Comment: you can start by clarifying, what you want to calculate.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  If you have $N$ choices to make all in all, just "label" the first $.6N$ as "type $1$", and so on.  Then you can draw randomly from a collection of $N$ balls.  Thus, if $N=10$, imagine you had $6$ Blue balls, $3$ Red ones, and $1$ Green one...and choose randomly among these.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @lulu : Yes you are right. There are N choices. & out of this N choices 60 must be done from 1st, 30 from 2nd & 10 from 3rd. But the selection of list must be in random fashion.

Comment: Ok, so just do it the way I said.  To implement it, in Excel say, lust make a list of elements $1\dots N$ labeled the way I said, and then choose an element from that list from a uniform random number generator ($RandBetween(1,N)$ calls that in Excel).

Comment: If what you really need is a random permutation of $1\dots N$ that is obtainable as well, but it is somewhat more work.  here is a reference to the usual way to automate that:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle